# Transactional eMail variables

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail, confirmation

What variable (or how do we get) the `Delivery Date` and the `customer comment` onto the outgoing customer order confirmation email in Magento 2?

Comment: whats the field name for deliverydate and customer comment?

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful
/From where you send a Email [custom email Function]

```
public function yourCustomMailSendMethod($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
{
    /* Here we prepare data for our email  */


/* Receiver Detail  */
$receiverInfo = [
    'name' => 'Reciver Name',
    'email' => 'receiver@address.com'
];


/* Sender Detail  */
$senderInfo = [
    'name' => 'Sender Name',
    'email' => 'sender@address.com',
];


/* Assign values for your template variables  */
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTempVariables['customer_comment '] = $comment ;
$emailTempVariables['delivery_date'] = $Delivery;
    $this->temp_id = $this->getTemplateId(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD);
    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();    
    $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);    
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();        
    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
}
```

Here we will use  “your_email_template.html” name for email template

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} 
<!-- pathe of template header-->

<!-- here customer_comment ,Delivery_Date are variables in which we
                                 asssign values when we use this template  for send mail-->

<!-- you can Modify content of template according to your requirement-->

<table>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Customer Comment"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var customer_comment}}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Delivery Date"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var delivery_date}}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr> </table>   {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}} <!--footer of template-->
```